# Jquery columnizer plugin: 40 times faster in Windows Firefox. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, browser

I have a number of large texts which I'm using a lightly-stripped-down version of the columnizer jquery plugin (https://github.com/adamwulf/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin) to turn into "columns" for use in another plugin. Columnizer is an OK performer for my purposes--as long as there is no floated content within the chunk being columnized.

Chrome, FF and IE10 all have similar performance on pure text or text with images and other simple html mixed in, for the most part. However, if you include floated content (images, in this case), things change dramatically:

```
Big Book w/ Images, roughly 700 columns created
Test condition                      Firefox (sec)    Chrome (sec)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Normal book build (images, floats)        31.5         1254.2
As above, but no images                   23.2           18.9
w/ images, but no floated images          25.1           24.7
Only a few floated images                 27.6         1010.9
Remove all images, tags except 'p'        21.3           18.9
```

As you can see, that is a huge, huge difference. (I do cache the builds, but because each browser/OS combo renders things slightly differently, I still have to build each one first in the "major" browsers. You haven't lived until you wait for Safari on an iPad to build this thing -- multiply the windows chrome numbers by 4.)

So my question: **What is firefox doing "right" without being asked, and what can I do to re-work the columnizer code to mimic it in the other browsers?** Columnizer is fairly "dirty" in that it does thousands (I think over 100,000 in this book's case) of appends, which I know is definitely Not Cool. Is it using document fragments? Some other trick?

Columnizer requires that the destination container (where it does its content flow) to be in the dom so that styles can be applied correctly (ie, no "display:none" and then toggling when done). In my CSS, I set this to position:absolute, visibility:hidden, as recommended. I'm thinking FF must view this set of attributes in a way the other browsers don't. Or...?

I should note at the end of the process, except for the slight font rendering differences, the output is identical among the browsers.

Comment: Although I don't know the answer, I would like to see your question in progress. Do you have a page or fiddle where we could see whats going on?

Comment: Please ensure you have the newest edition

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely certain this *answers* my own question, but I did make things a lot better, which in some ways is answer enough for me. **I'd love to actually learn why my solution made any difference.**

**Background:** I do as much "pre-formatting" of the book's text in PHP as I can, as it is much much faster to do clean-up and other mundane text chores server-side. This cleaned-up chunk of html is then thrown into a div, which is what I columnize. This container (let's call it "raw"), and the empty destination container for the columns ("dest"), need to be in the dom, so I have this CSS on a wrapper div which has "raw" and "dest" as children:

```
position: absolute; 
top: -2000px;
left: -2000px;
width: 700px;
height: 500px;
visibility: hidden; 
overflow: hidden;
```

This 'removed' the two divs from the page (as far as our eyeballs are concerned), but they're still in the dom, allowing Columnizer to work with them.

**Hmmm:** In Firefox, this was enough to make things work well, floats or no. But in Chrome, Safari and IE...well, look at the table in my original question. Yuck.

But by adding "position: absolute" to "raw", the other browsers' performance was increased dramatically. They're not as fast as FF, but not far behind. Instead of 1200+ seconds, Chrome now takes 40 seconds when presented with the full book. The ipad, instead of taking a glacial epoch, takes a couple of minutes.

Why? It's a mystery to me. Here's what seem to be the pertinent bits within columnizer, during its prep:

```
...
var $sourceHtml = $('div.raw'),
    $cache      = $('<div></div>'),
    $inBox      = $('#dest'),
    $destroyable, $col;
...
$cache.append($sourceHtml.contents().clone(true));
$inBox.empty();
$inBox.append($("<div style='width:" + options.width + "px;'></div>")); 
$col = $inBox.children(":last");
$inBox.empty();
try {
    $destroyable = $cache.clone(true);
} catch(e) {
    $destroyable = $cache.clone();
}
...
```

That empty div created as the cache should be in the DOM but outside of the HTML page at this point, since it has not been appended to anything yet. Eh? So as it is manipulated, the page shouldn't need to be repainted.

My half-arsed theory is that while FF recognizes that, the other browsers don't, and consider $destroyable to be within the painted area of the page--perhaps appending it to the body tag or even to "wrap" (though watching through Chrome's inspector showed no such thing)?

As nodes are stripped from $destroyable and appended to the columns being created, the other browsers repaint the page every time $destroyable is altered. Speedy with block and inline stuff, expensive when floats are added.

But to poke a hole in that half-baked idea: Trying to add "position: absolute" to $destroyable makes no difference. It's only when the original "raw" div has that attribute that things speed up.

Anyway, back to heavy drinking and ignorance. Please sigh patiently and make this a teachable moment, if you can!

Comment: This isn't enough to be an answer, the plugin has to work out how much space each screen element uses after its on the page.  In boundary cases, it will iterate alot of times, moving elements across the columns.  You may have asymptotic data.
Anything that makes the elements size easier to compute is good for this plugin